# Logging errors in NodeJS / Express / React stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, winston, morgan

I've been working on an application using React, NodeJS/Express. My question is how do I log the error (either into node console or external file) when the error is on the the backend API server?

For example, let's say I have an api endpoint "/api/example" that will fetch data from a database and process the data. In that process, I have a database class like

```
class DB {
    update(sql) {
           ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But when I call the method I made a typo so instead I called `db.updates(sql)`, the console won't show any errors like `Uncaught error: db.updates is not a function` and the request will just hang until its terminated.

So my question is how do I make the error appear on console? It's getting annoying since this eats up so much more time than it should.

I tried morgan and it seems to just be logging just the http requests? I also tried winston and I still don't see anything in the log file or console (though I'm not sure how to use it. I've attached my winston logger code at the very bottom).

I haven't had this problem before since I have always used template view engines like ejs before and when errors like this happen, the ejs page will render with the errors on it. Now with the react environment and an API server that's sending only json responses, the pages just goes into the loading state of the component and until fetch request failed.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Winston logger.js

```
import winston from 'winston'

const options = {
    file: {
        level: 'error',
        filename: `./logs/error.log`,
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: true,
        colorize: false,
    },
    console: {
        level: 'error',
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: false,
        colorize: true,
    },
};

let logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File(options.file),
        new winston.transports.Console(options.console)
    ],
    exitOnError: true,
});

logger.stream = {
    write: function (message, encoding) {
    transports (file and console)
        logger.info(message);
    },
};

export default logger
```

App.js

```
import logger from './logger'
import morgan from 'morgan'

...
app.use( morgan('combined', {stream: logger.stream}) )
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in my project we get the error in the route(try/catch):

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    //get the data
    res.status(200).json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

And manage the answer in the app.js:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  //TODO implement error log (e.g. WINSTON)
  res.status(errorStatus).json({"status": err.status, "data": err.data, "message": err.message});
});
```

Comment: Ah I see, I guess I'll just wrap all the routes in try catch block.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping your function calls in try/catch blocks and log the caught error

Comment: Ah I see, I guess I'll just wrap all the routes in try catch block.
Thank you.